# How to find which process is blocking Android MapFragment UI Thread

Tags: mapfragment, android-anr-dialog, mapactivity

Whenever i open an intent, then presses back sometimes give ANR. Which means something is blocking my UI Thread. How to handle this. Can i start my activity on a separate thread. Even though it's a single threaded model